# Issue with VBA code to sort date to today

Tags: excel, vba

```vb
Sub Macro7()
    With Worksheets("Summary_2023")
        With .Range(.Cells(4, "A"), .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp))
            .AutoFilter field:=1, Criteria1:=xlFilterToday, Operator:=xlFilterDynamic
        End With
    End With
End Sub
```

Hi all,

Im confused with this macro as it always lead to an error 1004: autofilter range method has failed. I create a macro to automatically sort Collom a. Shamefully, im not sure what the number 4 means to the next of a as I used record macro.

Kindly help, thanks

Comment: The 4 is the row number of the range you are trying to use.

Comment: I don't get any problem when I run your code. Put some sample data into your question so we can see if that is the cause

Comment: One cause of this error could be if you have any tables or pivot tables in the worksheet, below the data you are trying to filter.

Comment: @kevin there cannot be data under the table, the filtered range is the column A from row 4 till the last row.

Comment: @Blackcat to recreate the error: put some data in A4:A5, leave A6 blank, put some data in A7:A8 and format A7:A8 as table. The macro will throw the error. Or put any pivot table in A7.

Comment: Can also recreate the error if data starting in A4 is formatted as a table, and there is any other data in column A outside of the table.

Comment: Hi,Im not sure what I did but somehow the problem was solved- thanks!

Comment: You are not sorting, you are filtering by today's date. A 'macro-recorded' code looks like this: `Sheets("Summary 2023").Select: Range("A4").Select: Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select: Selection.AutoFilter: ActiveSheet.Range("$A$4:$A$14").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=1, Operator:=11, Criteria2:=0, SubField:=0`. As you can see, there are no `With`, `Cells`, `End` or user-friendly xl parameters. Your code is an improvement. Try to turn off auto filtering by using `.AutoFilterMode = False` between the two `With`-s. If the data is in an Excel table, this is handled differently.

Comment: @kevin i now see what you mean, of course two tables cannot be filtered with one filter.